# How to make a JTextField look like a JLabel

Tags: java, swing

In my program, I would like to have a `JTextField` look flush with the surrounding `JPanel` with no 3D.

Also, is there another way for this to be accomplished? What I want is to have a updatable component that can show highlightable text without the focus being able to be shifted into with tab.

Comment: 1) What should be highlighted? 2) If it's not focusable the user won't be able to insert text there. You need to be very clear with what you want.

Comment: The text inside the Component should be able to be highlighted

Comment: @user1803551 It's a question asking for a similar thing, but I believe that the questions are different enough that they warrant different questions.

Comment: I don't think so, you want to achieve (*"What I want is to have a updatable component that can show highlightable text without being able to be cycled into with tab.*") is the same thing and the answer there will answer your question, unless you didn't explain what you want correctly.

Comment: That solution you posted in your question (which should actually be posted as answer) is essentially the same as in the link and in the answer below.

Comment: I'm posting a specific solution. Also, the `setBackground()` bit took a bit of searching since just doing `setBackground(UIManager.getColor("RootPane.background")` does not work. Though I guess I should move it to an answer.

Comment: You don't need to do that background line at all. Just use `setOpaque(false)` or `setBackground(null)` as described in the linked answer.

Answer (score 2):

To acheive the text field looking flush you just need to remove the border of the `JTextField` (along with changing the colour as you have done).

```
aJTextField.setBorder(null);
```

As mentioned by @user1803551 if the text field is not focusable then the user won't be able to enter text, nor will they be able to highlight it.

If you want the user to be able to highlight the text, but not edit the text or have the cursor appear in the field then I suggest you set the field to not being editable

```
aJTextField.setEditable(false);
```

However at the moment this part of your question remains unclear (and should really be a new question) as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Curious, if the question is unclear, why do you answer it?

Comment: @user1803551 Well its really two different questions, The first (and the title) is about looks and warrants an answer. The second is about the behavior, which is the part that is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Set the background color to the surrounding `JPanel`'s background color with `setBackground(null)` or 'setOpaque(false)'.

To get a `Color` object with the `JPanel`'s background color, use `new Color(UIManager.getColor("RootPane.background").getRGB())`

Also, set the border to be null with `setBorder()`.

In addition, to allow highlighting without a visible change of focus, use `setEditable(false)`.

Comment: This is the answer in the duplicate question link. Why won't you just flag your own question as a duplicated and upvote the answer there?

Comment: Oh well, it was flagged anyway.